# quick way of filtering numpy array values

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'd like to filter a numpy array based on values from another array:

- if the value from another array is positive, keep it untouched in this array,
- if the value from another array is 0, change the value in this array to 0,
- if the value from another array is negative, invert the sign of the value in this array,

currently I have:

```py
import numpy as np
this = np.array([1, 2, -3, 4])
other = np.array([0, -5, -6, 7])

this[other == 0] = 0
this[other < 0] *= -1
print(this)
# [ 0 -2  3  4]
```

As shown, it needs to loop `other` twice to get the indices whose values are equal or smaller than 0, and it needs to loop `this` twice to change values. Is there a quicker way? (suppose `this` and `other` are very large arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) function to get indication of the sign of numbers:

```
this * np.sign(other)
```

---

```
array([ 0, -2,  3,  4])
```